# ueye undefined reference using catkin_make

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I stumbled upon a difficulty, when trying to work with uEye camera. I've added

```
#include "ueye.h"
```

to work with code:

```
HIDS hCam = 1;

INT nRet = is_InitCamera (&hCam, NULL);
```

Yet this is the output when I try to do catkin_make using my CMakeLists (http://pastebin.com/u8f4t2Fc)

```
CMakeFiles/ros_aruco.dir/src/ros_aruco.cpp.o: In function `main':
ros_aruco.cpp:(.text+0x578): undefined reference to `is_InitCamera'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I add to make it work?

Comment: Where is `is_InitCamera` defined and how?

Comment: In ueye.h file. Anyway, problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `${UEYE_LIBRARY}` to the target_link_libraries in CMakeLists.txt solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `is_InitCamera` is a function provided by uEye. To use such external functions you need to do two things:
- provide compiler with the function declaration, normally in an `.h` - you did this part
- provide linker with library containing the compiled function - the error message you quoted says that you did not do this part
How to provide linker with the library depends on your environment, but there is always some list of libraries where you need to add .lib, .a, or other library file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile with `gcc <your_filename> -lueye_api -o <output_filename>`. Found it on this [link](https://gist.github.com/ChristianUlbrich/7871863).